# mongodb date query JAVA and Talend

Tags: java, json, mongodb, talend

I have been using pymongo to do all my mongodb interactions, though now, I need to run a query from Talend without going through python.

I use the following query directly against mongodb:

```
db.votes.find({'dateUpdated': {$gte: (new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-5)))}});
```

Just running the date component gives me an ISODate thats 5 days old.

Talend uses JAVA and I'm unable to replicate the query there. I get the below errors:

```
{'dateUpdated': {$gte: (new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-5)))}}
                   ^
at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:198)
at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parseObject(JSON.java:231)
at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:195)
at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parseObject(JSON.java:231)
at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:195)
at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:145)
at com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:81)
at com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:66)
```

The JAVA code generated through Talends UI looks like this:

```
com.mongodb.DBObject myQuery_tMongoDBInput_1 = (com.mongodb.DBObject) com.mongodb.util.JSON
                    .parse("{'dateUpdated': {$gte: (new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-5)))}}");
```

I basically know zilch of JAVA but I'm hoping someone can help me put something into that .parse function that would get me posts that have dateUpdated newer than 5 days.

Thanks!